# What should I use for real-time geocoding: Google APIs or Android APIs?

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm in a very early stage of developing an android app that needs to make constant updates on the location of the user (near-exactly lat and long) while walking on the street. I'm not exactly sure if there is a class or method in Android that can help me (GPS?), or if I have to user something external, like Google Maps API (like geocoder).

So that's the question, Android can update my location or should i need the help of Google?

EDIT: I won't use this data to display it on a Google Map interface.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android framework provides a `location` API - see [Location Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html#location) and [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for more information.

To answer your question: Android can update your location.